# Rabbitmq commands are not working

Tags: 16.04, command-line, server, rabbitmq

When I perform `sudo rabbitmqctl add_user james mypassword` it returns:

```
Creating user "james" ...
Error: {badarg,
           [{erlang,group_leader,[undefined,<5490.18387.0>],[]},
            {rabbit_log,with_local_io,1,
                [{file,"src/rabbit_log.erl"},{line,99}]},
            {rabbit_auth_backend_internal,add_user,2,
                [{file,"src/rabbit_auth_backend_internal.erl"},{line,149}]},
            {rpc,'-handle_call_call/6-fun-0-',5,
                [{file,"rpc.erl"},{line,206}]}]}
```

I previously did not have a problem with this. However it has recently spawned this error and I'm not sure why. It also returns the same error when I try `sudo rabbitmqctl stop`:

```
Stopping and halting node rabbit@postr ...
Error: {badarg,[{erlang,group_leader,[undefined,<5490.18408.0>],[]},
                {rabbit_log,with_local_io,1,
                            [{file,"src/rabbit_log.erl"},{line,99}]},
                {rabbit,'-stop_and_halt/0-after$^0/0-0-',0,
                        [{file,"src/rabbit.erl"},{line,387}]},
                {rabbit,stop_and_halt,0,[{file,"src/rabbit.erl"},{line,384}]},
                {rpc,'-handle_call_call/6-fun-0-',5,
                     [{file,"rpc.erl"},{line,206}]}]}
```

My rabbitmq log file looks like this:

```
=ERROR REPORT==== 1-May-2018::21:48:06 ===
closing AMQP connection <0.14307.0> (174.824.62.219:39718 -> 174.824.62.219:5672):
{handshake_error,starting,0,
                 {amqp_error,access_refused,
                             "AMQPLAIN login refused: user 'james' - invalid credentials",
                             'connection.start_ok'}}
```

However the user `james` doesn't exist now, `sudo rabbitmqctl list_users` returns:

```
Listing users ...
guest   [administrator]
```

I've tried changing my `CELERY_BROKER_URL` from `'amqp://{}:{}@174.824.62.219/vhost'.format(config('RABBIT_USER'), config('RABBIT_PW'))` to `'amqp://guest:guest@localhost'` - however still getting the same error.

Any idea what the problem is?

**EDIT**

`service rabbitmq-server start` returns:

```
Job for rabbitmq-server.service failed because the control process exited with error code. 
See "systemctl status rabbitmq-server.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

so `systemctl status rabbitmq-server.service` returns:

```
● rabbitmq-server.service - RabbitMQ Messaging Server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/rabbitmq-server.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2018-05-03 07:30:37 UTC; 19s ago
  Process: 29946 ExecStop=/usr/sbin/rabbitmqctl stop (code=exited, status=2)
  Process: 8566 ExecStartPost=/usr/lib/rabbitmq/bin/rabbitmq-server-wait (code=exited, status=2)
  Process: 8565 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/rabbitmq-server (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 8565 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
```

and `sudo journalctl -xe` returns:

```
May 03 07:30:33 postr polkitd(authority=local)[1452]: Registered Authentication Agent for unix-process:8528:49657
May 03 07:30:37 postr polkitd(authority=local)[1452]: Operator of unix-process:8528:496573185 successfully authen
May 03 07:30:37 postr systemd[1]: Starting RabbitMQ Messaging Server...
-- Subject: Unit rabbitmq-server.service has begun start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit rabbitmq-server.service has begun starting up.
May 03 07:30:37 postr systemd[1]: rabbitmq-server.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
May 03 07:30:37 postr rabbitmq[8566]: Waiting for rabbit@postr ...
May 03 07:30:37 postr rabbitmq[8566]: pid is 8574 ...
May 03 07:30:37 postr rabbitmq[8566]: Error: process_not_running
May 03 07:30:37 postr systemd[1]: rabbitmq-server.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=2
May 03 07:30:37 postr systemd[1]: Failed to start RabbitMQ Messaging Server.
-- Subject: Unit rabbitmq-server.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit rabbitmq-server.service has failed.
-- 
-- The result is failed.
May 03 07:30:37 postr systemd[1]: rabbitmq-server.service: Unit entered failed state.
May 03 07:30:37 postr systemd[1]: rabbitmq-server.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
May 03 07:30:37 postr polkitd(authority=local)[1452]: Unregistered Authentication Agent for unix-process:8528:496
May 03 07:30:49 postr kernel: [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=9e:93:5d:bc:23:c5:5c:45:27:78:fb:30:08:00 SRC=77.72.82
May 03 07:30:54 postr sshd[8731]: Invalid user glassfish from 213.32.72.47
May 03 07:30:54 postr sshd[8731]: input_userauth_request: invalid user glassfish [preauth]
May 03 07:30:54 postr sshd[8731]: Received disconnect from 213.32.72.47 port 51824:11: Normal Shutdown, Thank you
May 03 07:30:54 postr sshd[8731]: Disconnected from 213.32.72.47 port 51824 [preauth]
May 03 07:31:21 postr sshd[8743]: Invalid user planos from 213.32.72.47
May 03 07:31:21 postr sshd[8743]: input_userauth_request: invalid user planos [preauth]
May 03 07:31:21 postr sshd[8743]: Received disconnect from 213.32.72.47 port 57492:11: Normal Shutdown, Thank you
May 03 07:31:21 postr sshd[8743]: Disconnected from 213.32.72.47 port 57492 [preauth]
May 03 07:31:43 postr sshd[8751]: Invalid user xbmc from 51.15.235.91
May 03 07:31:43 postr sshd[8751]: input_userauth_request: invalid user xbmc [preauth]
May 03 07:31:43 postr sshd[8751]: Received disconnect from 51.15.235.91 port 56274:11: Normal Shutdown, Thank you
May 03 07:31:43 postr sshd[8751]: Disconnected from 51.15.235.91 port 56274 [preauth]
May 03 07:31:44 postr sudo[8750]:    james : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/home/james/postr ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/bin/journal
May 03 07:31:44 postr sudo[8750]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by james(uid=0)
lines 1002-1040/1040 (END)
```

Comment: *Did you try turning it off and on again?* Unfortunately, [Unable to restart Rabbitmq: badarg rpc.erl line 206](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28428201/6164712) only suggest to kill the process…

Comment: I've added the results from trying that in my edit - do you see any clues to fix the problem in the output?

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo chown rabbitmq:rabbitmq /var/lib/rabbitmq/.erlang.cookie

sudo chmod 600 /var/lib/rabbitmq/.erlang.cookie
```

Comment: Hello and welcome on Ask Ubuntu. Could you please edit your post to provide some more details on what your commands do and why you suggest them?